# Patterns after recursive multiplication of the digits of a number until one digit is reached

Tags: number-theory

I am considering the process of repeatedly multiplying the digits of a number until a single digit number is reached.

Examples:

- 74 => 28 => 16 => 6
- 453 => 60 => 0
- 13429 => 216 => 12 => 2

It is interesting to look at the frequency of a certain digit appearing after doing this process for all numbers up to a certain number n. I have compiled a table of values up to n = 10000000 with the corresponding frequency as seen below:

[image]

(The numbers in the table represent the percent frequency of ending at the corresponding number for all integers up to the value n).

Some of the frequencies are easy to understand like the low amount of 1's. Since this only happens in numbers that ONLY have 1 (ex: 1, 11, 111, etc.).

I was hoping to understand the mathematical reasons for some of the other relationships I am seeing within this table. I have a few initial ideas for some but am unsure if they are correct and lack any strong evidence.

Patterns

1. Majority of numbers end at 0 and this increases as n increases

Initial thought: 0, is highly prevalent coming every 10 numbers and can easily be formed by multiplication of 5 with an even number.

2. After 0, why are 6 and 8 the next most prevalent ending digits?

Initial thought: they have the most factors making them more likely to occur. As well as the fact that many of the other digits are prime (2, 3, 5, 7)

3. Why is 8 more prevalent than 6 for small values of n but 6 more prevalent than 8 for larger values of n?

Comment: How are you so sure that $1$ only comes from numbers that only have $1$'s? What if something like $137739733713379331 => 11111111111=>1$ happens?

Comment: Not a rigorous understanding but looking through the factors of numbers like 11111111111 seem to always need a two digit prime number to be constructed. However, yes it was wrong of me to assume that 1 only comes from 1's for all n. I can compare the number of 1's expected if it only works with numbers that only have 1's to what actually happened for the numbers I have tested to see if its at least consistent for what I have. This would serve as mainly anecdotal evidence though.

Comment: The multiplicative digital root: see [OEIS sequence A031347](https://oeis.org/A031347).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $1$ can come only from $1\ldots 1$.

In order for $1\ldots 1=(10^n−1)/9$
to arise as the product of digits of some $x$, it must be the product of a power of $3$ and a power of $7$. In order for $(10^n−1)/9$ to be divisible by $7$, $n$ must be divisible by $6$ (i.e. the order of $10$ mod $7$ is $6$). But whenever $n$ is even, $(10^n−1)/9$ is divisible by $11$. Thus the only possibility left is that $(10^n-1)/9$ (and also $10^n-1$) is a power of $3$.  But this would mean $10^n - 3^m = 1$ for some integers $m$ and $n$ with $m$ and $n > 1$.  And that would contradict  [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the pattern with the ones. Any insight for the other 3 patterns mentioned, particularly #2 and #3 about the 6s and 8s?